# Passing a Mule payload object to Drools rule

Tags: mule, drools

I'm tying to build a mule flow which get data from a db, builds an object and then fires a drools rule. My problem is initialFacts-ref="#[payload.MapObject]" cannot be resolved. On deployment I'm getting 'No bean named '#[payload.MapObject]' is defined' How can I get the payload object into the rule as a fact?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"             xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:bpm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm/3.2/mule-bpm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">

<bpm:drools />

<flow name="myFlow" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/myflow" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:response-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        </http:response-builder>
    </http:listener>
    <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Finance" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.ID]]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <response>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </response>

    <component class="org.mule.transformers.myMapping" doc:name="myMapping"/>

   <bpm:rules doc:name="myRule" rulesDefinition="src/main/resources/rules/myRule.drl" initialFacts-ref="#[payload.MapObject]"/>

</flow>

</mule>

package org.mule.transformers;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

public class myMapping extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

    Object myMapping = null;

    if(message != null){

        myMapping = message.getPayload();

    }

    return myMapping;

} 
 }
```

Comment: General comments: `myMapping` should be referred to with a custom transformer message processor, not a `component` (and named `MyMapping` because Java). Also you should be able to load the rules from the classpath, with `rules/myRule.drl`, instead of relatively to the current workdir, as you're doing currently, which will fail when you package your app.

Comment: Now that I look at it closer, it seems `myMapping` does absolutely nothing: it sets the payload of the message to itself, basically. Just remove it.

Comment: Have you tried removing `<component class="org.mule.transformers.myMapping">` ? At best it does nothing, at worst it messes up with the message and Mule's capacity to handle it properly.

Comment: I see your point but I do need the  'component,' The example I'm showing is a simplified version of my work in which the 'component' builds  a complex object from data retrieved by the preceding db select,

Comment: Gotcha, so at least use a custom-transformer element, not a component one, since this is a transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialFacts-ref` refers to an existing Spring bean so you can't use a MEL expression as you try to. It is used for loading initial facts so that's why it's static.

In your case, it seems you just want to process the current message in a rule, not provide an initial set of facts to the rules engine. In this case, there's nothing to do. The current message payload is passed to Drools so you can access it directly.

Comment: Do you have initial facts?

Comment: Hi David I really appreciate your help, I think I do still need to specify     "initialFacts-ref" , I've seen examples defining a bean for the object type and initialFacts-ref="noFactsBean"   In my example the bean would be <spring:beans> 
<spring:bean name="noFactsBean" class="myMapping"/> 
</spring:beans>'

Comment: The rule fact is an object in the payload, so no I don't have initial fact as a bean. But without initialFacts-ref= the deploy fails with      'org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: null'

Comment: I don't understand why the initial facts would be of the same type of the payload message. I would expect a "noFactsBean" to be an empty collection.

Comment: I've made a break through on this issue I found that by adding   <set-payload value="#[message.payload.getObject()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/> after the drools rule, the rule becomes part of the flow rather than just being a branch of the Transformer. Now it deploys, rules fire, payload object is update, all good? Almost the weird part is myobject is duplicated in the payload, why would that be?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you when you say "the rule becomes part of the flow rather than just being a branch of the Transformer". Are you talking about parallel execution in multiple thread?

Comment: Before I added the Set Payload the flow entered the Transformer then branch to both the Rule and Response in parallel, although the flow did not continued beyond the rule, Now it flows from the Transformer to the Rule then the Set Payload followed by Response, which to makes more sense and would be what I'd expect to see, comments?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, probably worth opening a JIRA with MuleSoft to report it.

Comment: @sky.high, please share the changes you did, as I am also stuck with the same problem

Comment: Hi Saurabh, what part is presenting a problem ? Maybe post your code and I can take a look, my rules are working well now.